# JavaScript slideToggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

I've run into a little something that I can't figure out and I was wondering if you could have a go at it.

First off, there's this code:

```
<li class="mc002">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="label-container">
            <a class="btn">label 1</a>
            <a class="btn">label 2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="main-container">
            <div class="prj-title">
                <h3><a href="">New design for my website</a></h3>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button data-role="none" class="btn smry">summary</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="summary">
            </div>
            <div class="prj-footer">
                <h6>filed under:</h6>
                <span>webdesign, webdevelopment, UX design</span>
                <h6>skills:</h6>
                <span>html5, css3, javascript, php</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

and the JavaScript to make "summary" slide down:

```
$('.main-container .smry').click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".summary").slideToggle(100);
});
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't work. Can you help me out, please?

Comment: Aside the wrong selector you must set a content inside .summary div or you'll see anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method doesn't find siblings or cousins, it starts with the current element (`.smry`, in your case) and goes up through the ancestors, stopping when it finds a match (or returning an empty jQuery object if there is no match).

Try this instead:

```
$('.main-container .smry').click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".main-container").find(".summary").slideToggle(100);
});
```

This navigates up to the closest containing `.main-container` element and then uses [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to go back down to its associated `.summary` element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4a8JC/

Note that your code would need to be in a document ready handler and/or in a script block that appears after the elements in question.

(Note also that your summary div would need to have some actual content for this to make sense.)

Comment: Thank you! The code worked perfectly. I don't know how I didn't think about it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use just `$(".main-container .summary")` instead of `closest`. It's a little bit heavy operation. And do you have something in `.summary`. If it is an empty I don't think that you will see something.

Comment: Note that these elements are in an li element where it could reasonably be assumed there are a number of other sibling li elements with the same structure and classes. `$(".main-container .summary")` probably matches multiple elements.

Comment: This is not good advice in all cases. There could be more than one element on the page with the class `main-container` or `smry`. `$(this)` is the element clicked, and `.closest()` works with any number of elements. Also if you are concerned with speed, traversing is pretty fast. But keep in mind that `.closest()` does not do what OP wants.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your answers but, as "nnnnnn" said, there are many other "li" elements, and  "$(".main-container .summary")" would show them all.

Comment: I think that it's a matter of css selectors and naming. I don't like methods like closest, because they look tricky. Anyway @nnnnnn's answer is correct.